# Range of unsigned FLOAT values in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, precision, numeric

According to the [MySQL Numeric types documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-type-overview.html), among other, Float types have these properties:

> FLOAT[(M,D)] [UNSIGNED] [ZEROFILL]
>
> A small (single-precision) floating-point number. Permissible values are -3.402823466E+38 to -1.175494351E-38, 0, and 1.175494351E-38 to 3.402823466E+38. These are the theoretical limits, based on the IEEE standard. The actual range might be slightly smaller depending on your hardware or operating system.
>
> M is the total number of digits and D is the number of digits following the decimal point. If M and D are omitted, values are stored to the limits permitted by the hardware. A single-precision floating-point number is accurate to approximately 7 decimal places.
>
> UNSIGNED, if specified, disallows negative values.

I want to determine if the behavior of `unsigned float` is similar to the behavior of `unsigned int` where the the full bit depth of the decimal and mantissa is used to represent positive values, or if `unsigned float`s only prevent negative values.

Comment: I would be very surprised if the range changed.  The IEEE standard doesn't address unsigned values.

Comment: If you are asking this question (ie you need every bit to count), `float` is probably not the right choice; it is by design imprecise.

Comment: @Bohemian That's a good concern, but I'm not doing any calculating with these fields, just attempting to give it a stronger type.

Comment: @MattWalther calculating or just storing/retrieving verbatim, the problem is the same. If you need precision, don't use `float`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to determine if the behavior of unsigned float is similar to
>   the behavior of unsigned int where the the full bit depth of the
>   decimal and mantissa is used to represent positive values, or

No.  MySQL chose to use IEEE-754 Single precision Float for its `FLOAT`.  IEEE Float is "sign-magnitude", so the sign bit occupies a specific location of its own.  `INT`, on the other hand, is 2's complement encoding.  So, the bit for the sign can be either interpreted as a sign or as an extension of the value.  (Caveat: Virtually all current *computer hardware* works the way described in this paragraph; but there may be some that do not.  An antique example:  The CDC 6600 used 1's complement.)

> if unsigned floats only prevent negative values.

Yes.

It has to be said: If you're using the inherently imprecise `FLOAT` data type you should think through why your problem space prohibits all negative numbers. Do those numbers faithfully represent the problem space? Is `FLOAT`'s imprecision acceptable for what you're representing?

The idea that there can be *no computation* on floating-point numbers is illusory. Just generating them from integers involves computation. Yes, it's done directly on the computer chip, but it's still computation.

And, the example of packet loss is

1. precisely represented by two integers: number of packets lost / number of packets (you could call this a rational number if you wanted), or
2. approximately represented by a FLOAT fraction resulting from dividing one of those integers by the other.

With respect, you're overthinking this.

`FLOAT` always occupies 4 bytes, regardless of the options tacked onto it.  `DECIMAL(m,n)`, on the other hand, occupies *approx* (m/2) bytes.

`FLOAT(m,n)`, is probably useless.  The `n` says to round *in decimal* to n places, then store into a binary number (IEEE Float), thereby causing *another* rounding.

Comment: Would it matter if no calculations are being performed on these values? Is it better to give a field a "tighter" type that would prevent unexpected/non-sense values? For reference, these values are representing frame rate, and packet loss.